# Function prints value but returns "None"

Tags: python, function, printing, return

```
def findLineParam(sprotParam, pos):

    if line[:2] == sprotParam:
        start = pos
        while line[start] == " ":
            start += 1
        stop = start + 1 
        while stop < len(line) and not line[stop] in (" ", ";"):
            stop += 1
        print(line[start:stop]) # prints the correct value!
        return line[start:stop] # returns None?
```

To briefly explain the function of the code is that it should take an input string (keyword), e.g. "ID" and find this on a line in a text file then it should find the first value after white space reading to next " " or ";" and return this. I can see that when I print the line, it returns exactly what I want but when I return it, it returns "None".

Whenever I change the "sprotParam" to an input list instead (*sprotParam) it does return the values but also an equal amount of "None" corresponding to the lines in the file, which I believe indicates, that it iterates and performs operations on all lines, which it shouldn't.

Code calling the function

```
try:
    file = input("Enter filename: ")
except IOError as e:
    print("That is not a recognised filename. Error given: " + str(e)) 
    sys.exit(1) # Close the program

with open(file, 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        ident = findLineParam("ID", 2)
```

Comment: Please add the code that calls the function.

Comment: I have a much easier solution to your problem, but I am not *exactly* sure what you are trying to accomplish with your code.  Can you provide example file data, and your expected outcome?

Comment: Hi, @Phintac did you find a solution to the problem. I'm facing this currently and the answers on this post do not help.

Answer (score 1):

`line` isn't within the function's scope, so you need to pass it to the function as an argument:

```
def findLineParam(sprotParam, pos, line):
    if line[:2] == sprotParam:
        start = pos
        while line[start] == " ":
            start += 1
        stop = start + 1 
        while stop < len(line) and not line[stop] in (" ", ";"):
            stop += 1
        print(line[start:stop]) # prints the correct value!
        return line[start:stop] # returns None? 

with open(file, 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        ident = findLineParam("ID", 2, line)
```

### Update

Here is a simplified version of your code:

```
def findLineParam(sprotParam, file):
    for line in file.split(sprotParam):#split by parameter
        if line != '<':
            for item in line.split(): #split by whitespace
                if item != '=':
                    print(item)
                    return item

    raise Exception(f'No {sprotParam} parameters were found in the given file')

file = 'test.txt'
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    ident = findLineParam("ID", f.read())
```

Now, if you run this for `test.txt`:

```
<ID= 'foo'    > <div></div>
asdfnewnaf
```

It will return `'foo'`.

Comment: Hi Caleb, thank you for your comment, I tried incorporating your suggestion but it still returns "None" :(

Comment: @Phintac Added an update.  Let me know if isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0):

if your function must return something, you should return a default value (you only are returning on a if statement, so if you don't matche this if, you return None)
I know it's not solving you problem but it's better to get this ^^

Comment: But in that case, it was also not supposed to print anything

Comment: yeah it's why I'm saying it's not solving the problem. I should just "add a comment" instead of giving an "answer", right

Answer (score 0):

As @NoxFly suggested all paths doesn't return.

```
def findLineParam(sprotParam, pos, line):
    ret = ''
    if line[:2] == sprotParam:
        start = pos
        while line[start] == " ":
            start += 1
        stop = start + 1 
        while stop < len(line) and not line[stop] in (" ", ";"):
            stop += 1
        print(line[start:stop]) # prints the correct value!
        ret = line[start:stop] # returns None? 
   return ret

with open(file, 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        ident = findLineParam("ID", 2, line)
```

A much better approach will be to use regex instead of those while loops. 
for example the regex will find the value.

```
r"ID:([^(\s|;)]*)"
```